# Can't find an import statement that works with both unittest and running the module standalone

Tags: python

I'm figuring out python and trying to work through some weirdness with import statements and unit tests. I don't think this problem is anything too profound, just not clear from a beginners stand point.

The jist of the problem :

- If I have a certain import statement in a dev file, I can run tests.
- If I have a different import statement in the same dev file, I can run the file in python via cmdline to check syntax quick checks ("python.exe foo.py" for example).
- BUT - I can't seem to find a way to do both, at least without consistently modifying the dev file.

My directory structure :

```
Simple/
    dev/
        __init__.py
        foo.py
        bar.py
    test/
        __init__.py
        test1.py
```

The files are all pretty basic :

Bar.py :

```
## bar.py
def barfunc(arg1, arg2):
    return arg1 + arg2
```

Foo.py :

```
# foo.py 
from dev import bar

def foofunc(arg):
    return bar.barfunc(arg, arg)

print(foofunc(2))
```

my_test.py :

```
# my_test.py
import unittest
from dev import foo

class Testing(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_mytest(self):
    self.assertEqual(foo.foofunc(3), 6)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

So in the 'foo.py' file, If I have import statement 'from dev import foo' then I can run tests. Either through VSCODE test runner, or by console :

```
>> py -m unittest .\test\my_test.py
```

But if I try to run the 'foo.py' file, either by 'run' in vscode, or in cmd line "py .\dev\foo.py', I get this error :

```
>> py .\dev\foo.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:\Python\Simple\dev\foo.py", line 2, in <module>
    from dev import bar
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'dev'
```

Conversely, if I change the import statement in foo.py from "from dev import bar" to just "import bar", then I can run the module just fine. But I can't run tests - it won't even load the module. Receiving this error :

```
> ~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\python.exe ~\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2022.14.0\pythonFiles\testing_tools\unittest_discovery.py ./test *_test.py
cwd: .
[ERROR 2022-8-21 12:10:38.65]: Error discovering unittest tests:
 Failed to import test module: my_test
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File 
"C:\Users\b\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\unittest\loader.py", line 436, in _find_test_path
  module = self._get_module_from_name(name)
  File "C:\Users\b\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\unittest\loader.py", line 377, in _get_module_from_name
__import__(name)
  File "e:\Python\Simple\test\my_test.py", line 3, in <module>
from dev import foo
  File "e:\Python\Simple\dev\foo.py", line 2, in <module>
import bar
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'bar'
```

Is there some way to have it both ways? And why should the test module be affected by the import statement in dev code?

Comment: One of the ways to solve this is to set PYTHONPATH either by setting it as environment variable or by modifying  `sys.path` before your import statements

Comment: As you found out, you simply shouldn't run a module (in a package) like that. If it's only for syntax checking, use `py -m dev.foo` (no backslashes). And stick to `from dev import bar` (or `from . import bar`).